# Cannot read property 'reactiveProp' of undefined in vue-chartjs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js

I'm trying to use a component called "Vue-Chartjs" to create a LineChart.
But when i try to use the demo of Line Chart. An error occured.
I got: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reactiveProp' of undefined

[image]

My line-chart.js:

```
import { Line, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs'
const { reactiveProp } = mixins

export default {
  extends: Line,
  mixins: [reactiveProp],
  props: ['options'],
  mounted () {
    // this.chartData is created in the mixin.
    // If you want to pass options please create a local options object
    this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options)
  }
}
```

My dashboard.vue :

```
<template>
 <div class="small">
    <p>Dashboard</p>
    <line-chart :chart-data="datacollection"></line-chart>
    <button @click="fillData()">Randomize</button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import LineChart from '../charts/line-chart'
export default {
    components:{
        LineChart,
    },
    data () {
      return {
        datacollection: null
      }
    },
    mounted () {
      this.fillData()
    },
    methods: {
      fillData () {
        this.datacollection = {
          labels: [this.getRandomInt(), this.getRandomInt()],
          datasets: [
            {
              label: 'Data One',
              backgroundColor: '#f87979',
              data: [this.getRandomInt(), this.getRandomInt()]
            }, {
              label: 'Data One',
              backgroundColor: '#f87979',
              data: [this.getRandomInt(), this.getRandomInt()]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      getRandomInt () {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (50 - 5 + 1)) + 5
      }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finnaly i fixed it by clear the package-lock.json, remove node_modules
run

`npm install vue-chartjs chart.js --save`

and
run

`npm install`

and it is ok!

Answer (score 0):

You can go one step further and extract the reactiveProp out of mixins

```
import { Line, mixins: { reactiveProp } } from 'vue-chartjs'
```

Comment: Thanks bro, but there is a syntax error with your code when i implement it :(

Comment: @KiênĐinh what err?

Comment: im writing javascript, but seem above is typescript, right ?

Comment: @KiênĐinh no, its normal javascript. its called destructuring